# useEffect doesn't work after being dynamic import in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I been given a project. The base of website can shown but everything fetch inside useEffect did not. So i relized that problem is those useEffect.

So i found the component is dynamic in parent component with `ssr: true`

```
const Template = dynamic(() => import('@/groupTemplate'), {
  ssr: true,
  loading: () => null,
});
```

and in `Template.js` I try to log everywhere but only in useEffect it doesn't work.

```
function Templates1(props) {
  const { data, dispatch } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    const query = {
      filter: {
        status: '1',
        objectListsId: data.id,
        languagesId: data.languagesId,
      },
      attributes: 'adsPositionsId,description,title,images,url',
      range: [0, 0],
    };
    console.log('123');
    dispatch({
      type: 'webs/fetchAllAd',
      payload: query,
      callback: res => {
        setBanner(res?.result?.list?.[0] || []);
      },
    });
  }, []);
}
```

And my question is does this dynamic import make useEffect cant work or any reason. Thanks for helping me.

Hope to get reason for the issue